# Errors for calling CallScanBack (Xamarin Android bluetooth)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Bluetooth;
using Android.Bluetooth.LE;

namespace BluetoothBLE
{
[Activity(Label = "BLE", MainLauncher = true)]
public class BLE : Activity
{
    private BluetoothAdapter.ILeScanCallback mLeScanCallback;

    private ScanResult Result;

    private ScanCallback ScanCallback;

    private int Signal_Strength = 0;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.BLE_Layout);

        Button scan = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Scan);
        TextView view = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.BLE_Text);

        //BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)GetSystemService(BluetoothService);
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.Adapter;

        BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.BluetoothLeScanner;

        //To see if the deives support Bluetooth Low Energy
        //if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE))
        //{
        //    Toast.MakeText(this, Resource.string.ble_not_supported, ToastLength.Short).show();
        //    Finish();
        //}

        scan.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if(mBluetoothAdapter != null || !mBluetoothAdapter.IsEnabled)
            {
                bluetoothLeScanner.StartScan(ScanCallback);
                ScanCallback.OnScanResult(ScanCallbackType.AllMatches,Result);
                Signal_Strength = Result.Rssi;
                view.Text = Signal_Strength.ToString();
                Toast.MakeText(this, "List of Beacons found", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Bluetooth not Supported", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        };
    }

    public class Scan: ScanCallback
    {

    }
}
}
```

I keep getting this Error message Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException:  can someone explain to me what is this and how do I solve it. As, does it mean that I have to set a timer for it to stop? Any helps would be greatly appreciated. Sorry, If I am asking basic questions as this is my first time trying out Xamarin.

Comment: Your problem is not clear can you show us the sample code you are trying to use integrate in your project

Comment: Hi, I have just posted my entire coding to show the errors that I have.

Comment: Which java code did you use for reference sir? Or did you write this on your own?

Comment: I use Android Developer and Xamarin Android Bluetooth as a source of reference. However, as it is based not on Java I basically had to code myself from my understanding. The Program that I want this to do is to make it able to detect BLE devices.

Answer (score 0):

- You have to listen for specific intent broadcasted by OS when a Bluetooth device is found.

First, define a broadcast receiver in a new class.

```
public class BluetoothDeviceReceiver: BroadcastReceiver
{

}
```

Then, implement BroadcastReceiver abstract method OnReceive(Context, Intent). The data about discovered Bluetooth device is stored in intent.

```
class BluetoothDeviceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{

public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
            string action = intent.Action;

        if (action == BluetoothDevice.ActionFound)
        {
            // Get device
            BluetoothDevice newDevice = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);

    // now you could do your job with newDevice
    // etc. check if newDevice is not already in a list and then use it in a ListView
        }
  }
}
```

- Now, to make our BluetoothDeviceReceiver actually start receiving new bluetooth devices, register it either by declaring it in AndroidManifest.xml file or do it in the runtime. I would prefer the latter one as it is more flexible.

Call this in any context(typically in main activity's OnResume())

```
BluetoothDeviceReceiver bluetoothDeviceReceiver = new BluetoothDeviceReceiver();
mainActivity.RegisterReceiver(bluetoothDeviceReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound));
```

And don't forget to unregister it in your activity's OnPause()

```
mainActivity.UnRegisterReceiver(bluetoothDeviceReceiver);
```

- For a proper example check [here](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/BluetoothChat/DeviceListActivity.cs)

Comment: Hi is this for Bluetooth Low Energy or Classic Bluetooth?

Comment: I guess its low energy let me check

Comment: Check this out : https://www.hackster.io/daquilnp/getting-started-with-bluetooth-low-energy-using-xamarin-8d6db2